# Flash Builder: 1172 Definition Could not be found

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I have an actionscript project in Flash Builder and get 1172 errors on these lines:

```
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
```

i'm comming from flash where i have to set in the publish settings that i want to compile an AIR application. I can't find an equivalent in flash builder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Flash Builder 4, I don't think you can create an ActionScript only AIR Project using the project setup wizard.  You'll have to create an ActionScript project, and then manually add the AIR libraries to the classpath.

Comment: That's correct.  You can't create an Air app with pure actionscript.  You need the Air SDK + Flex SDK together for this to work.

Comment: great, that worked! I added 'FlashCS5root/Common/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/AIR2.0/airglobal.swc' to the library path. thanks!

Comment: thanks for including this comment, Mat. It just solved an AIR issue for me.